# I want to make a function that print out insert query by function in php. Question :

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

> table name: emp
>   column name: (emp_name, emp_salry,emp_city,emp_country)
>   column values:("ali","2000","Multan","Pakistan")

i have an array

```
$info = array(
  'emp_name'=>'Ali',
  "emp_salery"=> '2000',
  "emp_city"=> 'Multan',
  "emp_country"=> "Pakistan"
);
```

I want to call a function

```
insert($info,"emp");
```

which return the answer in the browser as follow

```
insert into emp (emp_name,emp_salery,emp_city,emp_country) value("ali",'2000','multan', "Pakistan");
```

What is the solution using loops?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: i want to solve simple and essay way which  easy to understand any one,

Comment: Welcome. Have you done anything yet? Why are "ali" and "multan" inserted lowercase and "Pakistan" is not, what is the rule for those? How is `javascript` related to the question?

Comment: itis my mistak that i inserted "Ali" and " Multan" in lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function insert($info,$table){
    $qry    = "";
    $fields = "";
    $values = "";
    foreach($info as $field => $value){
        $fields.=$field.",";
        $values.="'".$value."',";
    }
    $qry.="insert into ".$table." (".rtrim($fields,',').") value (".rtrim($values,',').")";

    return $qry;
}

$info = array(
       "emp_name"   => "Ali",
       "emp_salery" => "2000",
       "emp_city"   => "Multan",
       "emp_country"=> "Pakistan"
);

echo insert($info,"emp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $info = array(
             'emp_name'=>'Ali',
             "emp_salery"=> '2000',
             "emp_city"=> 'Multan',
            "emp_country"=> "Pakistan");
    $tblname = "emp";

    print_r(insert($info,$tblname));

    function insert($info,$tblname){
      $q = "insert into ".$tblname ."(";
      $keys ="";
      $val = "";
      foreach($info as $key=>$value){
        $keys .= $key.",";
        $val .= "'".$value."',"; 
      }
      $keys = rtrim($keys, ',');
      $val =rtrim($val, ',');
      $q .= $keys.") value(".$val.")";
      return $q;
    }
```

**Output**

```
insert into emp(emp_name,emp_salery,emp_city,emp_country) value('Ali','2000','Multan','Pakistan')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use the following function
$array_col=array_keys($info);
$array_val=array_values($info);

function get_insert_syntax($table,$info){
$cols="insert into $table(";
$vals="values (";
for($i=0;$i<count($info);$i++)
{
    if($i<(count($a)-1)){
        $cols.=$array_col[$i].',';
        $vals.="'".$array_val[$i]."',";
    }
    else{
        $cols.=$array_col[$i].')';
        $vals.="'".$array_val[$i]."')";
    }

}
return $cols.' '.$vals;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$info = array(
  'emp_name'=>'Ali',
  "emp_salery"=> '2000',
  "emp_city"=> 'Multan',
  "emp_country"=> "Pakistan"
);


$table="emp";
function get_insert_syntax($table,$info){
    $array_col=array_keys($info);
$array_val=array_values($info);

$cols="insert into $table(";
$vals="values (";
for($i=0;$i<count($info);$i++)
{
    if($i<(count($info)-1)){
        $cols.=$array_col[$i].',';
        $vals.="'".$array_val[$i]."',";
    }
    else{
        $cols.=$array_col[$i].')';
        $vals.="'".$array_val[$i]."')";
    }

}
echo $cols.' '.$vals;
}
 get_insert_syntax($table,$info);
```